# Simple But Confusing Conditional Probabilties

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

This is a classic question, and I understand the answer from one approach, but I'm trying to understand the underlying conditional probabilities.

> We have two bags: Bag A contains 5 keys, Bag B contains 7 keys.
> One of the 12 key's fits a lock.
> If we select a bag and key at random what is the probability we find the correct key $P(F)$.

**Answer:**
We partition the event space into 4 possibilities, and sum the appropriate events multiplied by the probability of finding the key given that event.

1. $A_1$ Key in Bag A, and we Pick A: $P(A_1) = 5/12 • 1/2 = 5/24$
2. $A_2$ Key in Bag B, and we Pick A: $P(A_2) = 7/12 • 1/2 = 7/24$
3. $B_1$ Key in Bag B, and we Pick B: $P(B_1) = 7/12 • 1/2 = 7/24$
4. $B_2$ Key in Bag A, and we Pick B: $P(B_2) = 5/12 • 1/2 = 5/24$

$P(F) = 1/5P(A_1) + 1/7P(B_1) = 1/12$

**Questions:**
I'm struggling to work out the conditional probability's $P(F|A_1)$ & $P(F|A)$:
And if i have worked them out correctly, why they make sense:

1. $P(F|A_1)$ = $\frac{P(F \cap A_1)}{P(A_1)}$ = $\frac{(1/5)(5/24)}{5/24}$ = $1/5$ =  $\frac{P(A_1|F)P(F)}{P(A_1)}$ = $\frac{P(A_1|F)1/12}{5/24}$

- Therefore: $P(A_1|F) = 1/2$
- I think $1/5$ makes intuitive sense, but i'm not happy with my calculations:
- I've basically written: $P(F|A_1) = \frac{P(F|A_1)P(A_1)}{P(A_1)}$ This feels wrong? A tautology?
- $P(A_1|F) = 1/2$ I'm unsure of, and am not finding intuitive.
- I guess $P(A_1|F) = 1/2$ could be saying that if we know we have found the key, then it had to be in either scenario $A_1$ or $B_1$ but given they are weighted differently i'm unclear why $P(A_1|F) = 1/2$

2. $P(F|A) =  \frac{P(F \cap A)}{P(A)}$ = $\frac{(5/24)(1/5)}{1/2}$ = $1/12$ = $\frac{P(A|F)P(F)}{P(A)}$ = $\frac{P(A|F)1/12}{1/2}$

- Therefore: $P(A|F) = 1/2$
- Again, I think $P(F|A) = 1/12$ makes intuitive sense, as just because we have picked bag A, doesn't make it any more likely, that the Key is in  Bag A, and hence doesn't effect the overall probability of finding the key.
- $P(A|F) = 1/2$ like before is bothering me, I suppose the previous logic could apply? We've found the key, which bag did we pick, it has to be one of the two 50/50....But that doesn't feel right?

Really appreciate the help deciphering these conditional probabilities and the intuition behind them! Thanks!

**Updated Context**: A screenshot of the original question and solution

[image]

Comment: Where do (1) - (4) come from and what do they mean?  The problem describes a two-step process whose chances depend on which bag the correct key is in (which is unknown): if it's in A it will be selected with $1/2\times 1/5=1/10$ probability and if it's in B it will be selected with $1/2\times 1/7 = 1/14$ probability.  *That's all one can say from the information given.*

Comment: Hey @whuber thanks so much for commenting. It's from the course pack directly. I'll include a picture for context at the bottom. Would love your help on this!

Comment: The course pack was probably written by an unsupervised graduate student and their work hasn't been checked ;-).  (I did that kind of work as a graduate student ...)  The answer, to me, is total nonsense because there is no basis for those probabilities and, as I stated previously, there's not enough information to provide an answer.  It can help to change the numbers a little: what if A had one key and B had a million keys? You would have a $1/2$ chance of picking the working key if it's in A and less than a one-in-a-million chance if it's in B. That's intuitively obvious, I hope.

Comment: Hey @whuber thanks again for the reply, this slipped through my Inbox! So I thought about it some more. Would it not make sense for example if the keys are allocated at random, and we pick a bag at random, and then we pick a key at random. That the probabilities laid out $C_1$ to $C_4$ make sense?. I.e. as per your example we would also have to factor in the fact that there would only be 1/million and one  chance, the key was put in bag A?

Comment: I've managed to find the professor responsible for the course pack and I can contact him (my course is virtual and poorly staffed, so not strait forward) nonetheless he is a professor I know of and respect. What would be SO helpful, is if you could just write very briefly what you think would be the appropriate question to ask him? To untangle why perhaps the question doesn't make sense. I can formulate the question, I just think you'll do a better job! Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I trust that the example I gave would suffice to indicate what the problem is.  The suggested solution you quote makes implicit assumptions that are not part of the problem; namely, that the key has previously been allocated uniformly at random or that one may act as if this is the case.  That assumption is not supported by any facts or legitimate theory (although you might hear some people cite the so-called "principle of sufficient reason," but that's only a hope, not a principle).

Comment: Okay great and thank you for responding so quickly after my absence! I've wrote this question to ask the professor. "How do we arrive at the probabilities 5/12 and 7/12 are we mean't to assume that the keys were already allocated to the bags uniformly at random. Otherwise without this assumption...we are just left with the probability of picking the bags, without this being weighted by the probability that the right key ended up in the bag." Does that sound reasonable to you?

Comment: Also...if we make that assumption, which then makes the probabilities make sense,,,and if you have the time? Are you able to answer or provide guidance for the intended question, regarding the conditional probabilities. No worries if you're too buys right now, thanks!